# Bash script using mysql command with variables failing

Tags: bash, shell-script, mysql

I have a script to clone a vhost and associated db - however one of the mysql commands doesn't work. It fails and ends up outputting the mysql version number and 'how to use' info as if it hasn't been passed valid arguments - no error is given though.

An abbreviated version of the script is below - it's the line that should create the new database and grant privilidges that is failing. I'd appreciate any guidance on what I've got wrong or how to track down the problem.

Thanks.

```
#!/bin/bash -e
clear
echo "MySQL Admin Password: "
read -s mysqlpass
echo "New Site name (short, a-zA-Z only)"
read -e newsitename
echo "Last chance - sure you want to run the script? (y/n)"
read -e run
if [ "$run" == y ] ; then

    # This command doesn't work
    dbsetup="CREATE DATABASE "$newsitename"_db;GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON "$newsitename"_db.* TO 'site_usr'@'localhost';FLUSH PRIVILEGES;"
    mysql -u root -p$mysqlpass -e "$dbsetup"

    mysqldump -u root -p$mysqlpass template_db > temp.sql

    dbimport=$newsitename"_db < temp.sql"
    mysql -u root -p$mysqlpass $dbimport

else
    exit
fi
```

Comment: See [bash pitfall number 20](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#A.5B_bar_.3D.3D_.22.24foo.22_.5D).  Also **[quote your variables](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766/135943)**.

Comment: Also, why are you even setting a variable `dbsetup` if you only use it once?

Comment: Quotes were the problem - thanks.
It was just in a variable as this started by trimming down a much larger script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
dbsetup="CREATE DATABASE ${newsitename}_db;GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ${newsitename}_db.* TO 'site_usr'@'localhost';FLUSH PRIVILEGES;"
```

Double quotes will corrupt your string.

Answer (score 0):

This one worked for me in shell script:

```
environment_id=10

mysql -u root -proot dbname -e "update environment SET deployment_status = 1 WHERE environment_id = '${environment_id}'";
```